# Python binance APIError(code=-1022): Signature for this request is not valid

Tags: python, binance

I am following the api docs to try and create a simple test script which creates a test order. However I am getting the error `APIError(code=-1022): Signature for this request is not valid.`
After searching on google, I see no relevant answers as my code does not even request a signature input. I am using code from many tutorials and it is identical to their. I have ensured the key and secret is correct/passed through correctly, I have tested this by printing it out and doing other calls with the config.

Can anyone assist me learning this API or have experience with it?

My code:

```
import datetime
import config
from binance.client import Client
import json
import time
import random
import os

from binance.enums import *
binanceClient = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
order = binanceClient.create_test_order(
    symbol='BTCUSDT',
    side=SIDE_BUY,
    type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity=100
    #price='0.00001')

print(order)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you've pasted wrong credentials to your API_KEY and API_SECRET variables. Found the typo, fixed it for me

It also can be caused by dozen of other things, see this thread:

https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I was getting the same error with this

```
takeProfitOrder = binanceClient.futures_create_order(
    symbol = coin, side = oppositePose, type = 'TAKE_PROFİT_MARKET',
    stopPrice = float(round(float(openPrice) * 1.05, 8)),
    closePosition = 'true')
```

I replaced `ORDER_TYPE_MARKET` with `TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET` so I think your type parameter is wrong